Forwarding from one interface to another in a docker container
I have a wireguard container on a docker network, the docker network subnet is 10.18.0.0/16. The container ip is 10.18.0.2 and is receiving data on eth0, which I can see with tcpdump from within the container. I need to forward all data to the wg0 interface at 10.10.10.1 and from wg0 to eth0 (so bidirectional). I have tried the following:
  docker exec --privileged wireguard sh -c "
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
    sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 dev wg0
  "

And I tried:
 docker exec --privileged wireguard sh -c "
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
    ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 dev wg0
  "

And what is automatically generated for the server wg0 config:
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = 
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# peer1
PublicKey = 8qoHrFiwP3ZLKSoaSid8aSCd3UdzNK1rtG83bf1GG08=
PresharedKey = w2EcjRTa/xlNoEtKQGUWHJy+yOR4kSUTRIjaAzQImv0=
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.2/32

and wg show:
root@65ba9c130b82:/# wg show

interface: wg0

public key: NGUwwvrxBkW6afwyiztMieUHOlBi/dIDxHEx8zHIP1M=

private key: (hidden)

listening port: 51820

peer: 8qoHrFiwP3ZLKSoaSid8aSCd3UdzNK1rtG83bf1GG08=

preshared key: (hidden)

endpoint: 10.254.254.75:63164

allowed ips: 10.10.10.2/32

latest handshake: 55 seconds ago

transfer: 936 B received, 600 B sent

My container:
# Launch WireGuard container
  
if
 ! docker run -d --name wireguard \
    --privileged \
    --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
    --cap-add=SYS_MODULE \
    --sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1 \
    --sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 \
    -e PUID=$(id -u) \
    -e PGID=$(id -g) \
    -e TZ=Etc/UTC \
    -e SERVERURL=auto \
    -e SERVERPORT=51820 \
    -e PEERS=$NUM_PEERS \
    -e INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.10.10.0/24 \
    -e ALLOWEDIPS=10.10.10.0/24 \
    -e PEERDNS=auto \
    -v "$WIREGUARD_CONFIG_DIR:/config" \
    -p 51820:51820/udp \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    --network $NETWORK_NAME \
    lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest; 
then
    echo -e "${RED}Error: Failed to start WireGuard container.${RESET}"
    exit 1
  
fi

I have tried many different things but nothing seems to work. No data is ever forwarded to wg0 or from wg0 to eth0. The wg0 interface is up and is communicating with the client, I can ping both ways over the wireguard link.
Here is the output of my iptables in my container: https://pastebin.com/LDbzX11s
Any help is appreciated!

Which / What kind of hosts / destinations are you trying to access from the WG client exactly? Can you access them from the docker container itself? What's the AllowedIPs= in the client conf? (Btw, you don't actually need any ACCEPT rule in filter/FORWARD when the chain policy is ACCEPT and there is no DROP or REJECT rule in it.)

The wireguard connection seems fine, there is a handshake and I can ping both ways. I just cant route traffic coming into the container on eth0 to wg0. This seems purely server side.

Okay so everything is correct and it should be working.
